# How to send textbox value to server using ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an HTML form which contains a username textbox and a submit button.

When a user inputs a name in the username textbox, I want to take that value and send it over to the server so I can check whether the username has already been taken by another user or not.

Here is my code for creating the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="JquerySock.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-    scale=1">    
<script> 
function Usernameerrorfunc(field, errordiv, Notallowcharserror_SPN){

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Registeration_Div" class="Registeration_Div">

<form class="Registration_Form" id="Registration_Form" action="../postr" method="POST">

    <div id="Registeration_Username_DIV" class="Registeration_Username_DIV">
        <input type="text" id="Registeration_Username_box" class="Registeration_Username_box"
            placeholder="" name="UserName" maxlength="30" onblur="Usernameerrorfunc(this, 'Usernameerror_spn', 'Usernamenowallow_spn');" onclick="textboxfocus(this)"/>

    </div>
    <div class="Registration_Submit_Div">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="SumbitForm_btn" class="SumbitForm_btn" name="Submit_btn"/>
    </div>

</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `jQuery.ajax()`. Please check below the answer hope it will work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method in jQuery:

```
function postUsernameToServer() {
   var username = $("#Registeration_Username_box").val();

   $.ajax({
       url: "http://YourServerUrl",
       type: "POST",
       data: { username: username },
       success: function() {
           alert('Successfully connected to the server');
       }, 
       error: function() {
           alert('Something went wrong');
       }
   });
}
```

To invoke this using a button click (From my comment) you could do the following:

```
<button id="checkUsername">Check username</button>

$("#checkUsername").on("click", function() {
    postUsernameToServer();
});
```

Ensure that you have the jQuery library imported to use the function. 
If you did not want to use the jQuery and rather native JavaScript you can use the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: thanks for your response, but can you tell me where to use this function at, in textbox inblur= or somewhere else

Comment: @jacky - you can call it by using `postUsernameToServer()`.  I would recommend a button click.  Using an `onblur` event doesn't seem like the correct approach.  I have included an example on how to do this in my answer.

Comment: i may say you are right, but i don't want the user to press the button every time they input a name, i would prefer it to be automatic

Comment: @jacky - then `onblur` may be the best approach for you in this scenario, if the user loses focus on the textbox then the AJAX request will be submitted.  I hope you got this sorted.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

Use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**Code :**

```
function submitFormData() {
var name = document.getElementById("Registeration_Username_box").value;
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'username=' + name;
if (username == '') {
alert("Please Enter the Username");
} else {
// AJAX code to submit form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "checkUsername.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(data) {
alert(data);
},
error: function(err) {
alert(err);
}
});
}
return false;
}
```

I am giving example in `php` for checking the username. You can use any language accordingly.

**checkUsername.php :**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server..
$db = mysql_select_db("dbname", $connection); // Selecting Database
//Fetching Values from URL
$username=$_POST['username'];
//Select query
$query = 'select * from user_table WHERE name = "'.$username.'";
$query_result = mysql_query($query);
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result);

do
{
  echo json_encode($res);
}while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result));
}
mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed
?>
```